# salvando lista de dict em arquivo

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, lista, dicionário

tenho uma função que salva uma dict em um arquivo, mas isso é simultâneo, ou seja, a todo momento tenho uma dict nova. Não consegui aplicar o conceito de append para esse problema.

## O Arquivo está sendo salvo dessa forma:

```
 {
"num_conta": "11_OPEN.json",
"item_num": "333",
"item_desc": "COCA 3",
"item_price": "5.00"
 }
{
"num_conta": "11_OPEN.json",
"item_num": "222",
"item_desc": "FRANGO PEDACO",
"item_price": "5.00"
 }
```

## Gostaria que fosse uma lista de dict, dessa forma:

```
[
{
"num_conta": "11_OPEN.json",
"item_num": "333",
"item_desc": "COCA 3",
"item_price": "5.00"
 }, 
{
"num_conta": "11_OPEN.json",
"item_num": "222",
"item_desc": "FRANGO PEDACO",
"item_price": "5.00"
 }
]
```

## Minha Classe

```
class Conta:
     def __init__(self, num_conta, item_num, item_desc, item_price):
       self.num_conta = num_conta
       self.item_num = item_num
       self.item_desc = item_desc
       self.item_price = item_price
```

## E aqui minha função para salvar o arquivo:

```
if not os.path.exists('data/today/CHECK/' + conta.num_conta):
    with open('data/today/CHECK/' + conta.num_conta, 'w') as arquivo:
        json.dump(conta.__dict__, arquivo, indent=4)
        arquivo.close()
else:
    arquivo = open('data/today/CHECK/' + conta.num_conta, 'a')
    # json_string = json.dumps(data_request)
    json.dump(conta.__dict__, arquivo, indent=4)
    arquivo.close()
```

Qualquer ajuda é bem vida, Obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver o meu problema da seguinte forma:
**Salvo o primeiro item como uma lista de dict:**

```
if not os.path.exists('data/today/CHECK/' + conta.num_conta):
    print('Arquivo Json não existe')
    lista_instancia = [conta.__dict__]
    with open('data/today/CHECK/' + conta.num_conta, 'w') as arquivo:
        json.dump(lista_instancia, arquivo, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
        arquivo.close()
```

**Se o arquivo já existe, eu instancio o item do arquivo, adiciono os demais em uma nova lista e salvo, a saída é a que eu postei na pergunta**.

```
    else:
    arquivo = open('data/today/CHECK/' + conta.num_conta).read()
    objeto_json = json.loads(arquivo)
    objeto_json.append(conta.__dict__)
    arquivo_new = open('data/today/CHECK/' + conta.num_conta, 'w')
    json.dump(objeto_json, arquivo_new, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
    arquivo_new.close()
```

Eu acho que teria uma forma mais platônica de resolver isso, por exemplo em vez de instanciar o item ja salvo no arquivo e gravar tudo novamente com os itens novos, apenas salvar os novos.

Answer (score 0):

Bom, uma solução possível é usar o *garbage colector* para pegar o dicionário de cada instância da sua classe, adicionar esses dicionários em uma lista e salvar a lista com o pickle. Veja:

```
import gc
import pickle

class Conta:
     def __init__(self, num_conta, item_num, item_desc, item_price):
       self.num_conta = num_conta
       self.item_num = item_num
       self.item_desc = item_desc
       self.item_price = item_price

conta1 = Conta(1,2,3,4)
conta2 = Conta(3,5,7,9)

#criando uma lista de dicionários das instâncias da classe Conta

lista_instancia =[]
for obj in gc.get_objects():
    if isinstance(obj, Conta):
        lista_instancia.append(obj.__dict__)

print(lista_instancia)
```

Output:

```
[{'num_conta': 1, 
'item_num': 2, 
'item_desc': 3, 
'item_price': 4},
{'num_conta': 3, 
'item_num': 5, 
'item_desc': 7, 
'item_price': 9}]
```

Salvando:

```
f = open('minha_lista.pkl', 'wb')
pickle.dump(lista_instancia, f)
f.close()
```

Comment: Oi Lucas, muito obrigado pela resposta, consegui resolver de uma forma mais simples mas não sei se é a forma mais platônica. Estou postando o código com a explicação.